# Java JFrame and another class interaction

Tags: java, interaction

I've found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393954/java-with-jframe-and-class-interaction), but it's still be unclear for me.

So, I have a main class ProcessorCalculations(), from which I call MainFrame() class. In MainFrame class user should choose the folder. How I can transmit the JFileChooser() object from MainFrame() to ProcessorCalculations()?

I've tried to implement the hint from the link above:

```
   ProcessorCalculation processor = new ProcessorCalculation();
   MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame(processor);
```

But I don't know how to call `processor` methods from `mainFrame` without creating new objects.
Even I dont't know the correct question I should ask Google.
Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the code written above, then you're passing the current processor instance into your MainFrame constructor. What are you doing with the reference from within this constructor? Are you settinga a ProcessorCalculation instance to this reference? Please show us your constructor.

Your MainFrame class should look something like...

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
   // your ProcessorCalculation field  
   private ProcessorCalculation processor;

   public MainFrame(ProcessorCalculation processor) {
      // set the field with ref passed in parameter
      this.processor = processor; 

      // of course other code goes here
   }

   public void someMainFrameMethod() {
      // use the reference
      processor.someProcessorMethod();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create  an attribute say for example `files` in the mainframe by which the  contents of `JFileChooser()` are referenced ( you may say contents are stored in this attribute ). If this attribute is private put getter setter methods in the Mainframe for this attribute ( to make it accessible from other classes)  now coming back to your `ProcessorCalculation` class when you write `mainFrame.getFiles()` ( you have already created object `mainFrame` object there) it returns the data you wanted in this class.

In case you still face a problem please ask for a coded solution I will do.